# Cannot read property getPackageManager of undefined in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I referred this [nativescript-appList Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-applist). I'm getting this runtime error Cannot read property `getPackageManager` of undefined.

I'm running this below code inside constructor in angular2-nativescript

```
import * as AppList from "nativescript-applist";

 // inside the constructor

 console.log("First", "Test");

    AppList.getInstalledApps(function(apps) {

        console.log("Second", "Test");

        }, {
            withIcons: true
        });
```

In command prompt I'm unable to see this log console.log("Second", "Test"); .I can see only this log console.log("First", "Test");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin seems to be incompatible with an Angular project but there is an easy fix to make it work. In order to do that you will need to directly modify the source code of the plugin. Either clone the repo and apply the change below and then `npm pack` to produce newly modified **tgz** file or install the plugin and directly modify the code in `node_modules/nativescript-applist/Apps.android.js` (this is not the good approach as all changes will be removed when you delete node_modules folder)

To make the plugin work in Angular do the follwing
- open `node_modules/nativescript-applist/Apps.android.js`
- move the first two lazily loaded properties inside the method

e.g. before

```
var androidApp = app.android;
var androidAppCtx = androidApp.context;

function getInstalledListOfApps(callback, cfg) {
    // more code follows here
```

after

```
function getInstalledListOfApps(callback, cfg) {
    var androidApp = app.android;
    var androidAppCtx = androidApp.context;

    // more code follows here
```

And you are good to go!

Comment: thanks for your answer. it doesn't worked.I tested it.

Comment: I have created a test project and it works as expected on my side with the changes above - are you sure you are making the changes in the source file of the plugin? Keep in mind that in order those changes to take effect you would need to keep `node_modules folder` but delete `platforms` folder and rebuild the project

Comment: Thanks it worked as you said. I removed platforms and add it again.